# JPA Hibernate. How to find the dialect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to develop a REST API for a school project. How can I find the correct version for the dialect? I don't really know a lot about the topic, but I can understand that Hibernate is included with the JPA dependency?

If not, do I have to install it separately somehow? I can see that the compiler is auto-filling my property selection, so I guess that Hibernate comes with the dependency.

I am developing the project on Spring Boot with the following dependencies:

- Spring Web
- Spring JPA
- MySQL driver

I tried this Hibernate property but I am getting an error

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

This my pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecureSoftwareDevProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SecureSoftwareDevProject</name>
    <description>SecureSoftwareDevProject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am running MySQL server 8.0.31.

Comment: Well what JDBC JAR file are you including in your project's `pom.xml` file.  We need to know this.  Also, please include the underlying database vendor and version.

Comment: Edited in the answer to your questions I hope that was what you were asking for?

Comment: I think I found a possible work around. Deleting completely the command spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect automatically marks the dialect as : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect. Although I dont know if this will break something in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 uses Hibernate 6. Hibernate 6 changed how dialects work, and you need to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` (which configures itself based on your actual server version). The version specific dialects containing `InnoDB` in their name were removed in Hibernate 6, but there are still some version specific dialects (e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`), but those were deprecated with the release of Hibernate 6.

However, as pointed out by [Raffael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806580/raffael) in the comments, by default Hibernate 6 will automatically (based on connection information) select a dialect for you when it is not configured. So in most cases, simply removing the explicit configuration of the dialect will work best.

Comment: Hibernate 6 automatically finds out the correct dialect. There is no need to specify the dialect manually. See the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#basic-configuration-settings)

Comment: @Raffael It is not (always) needed, but you _can_ still specify it, and if you migrate from a previous version, you'll likely have it listed explicitly.

Comment: @Raffael I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL server 8.0.31, adding this should work on your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: Hibernate 6 deprecated `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`. The recommended way is to use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`.