# Spring JPA + Hibernate + Postgres - unable to perform "FOR UPDATE OF" query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to implement pessimistic write locking on table without locking a related ones using JPA and Hibernate on Postgres database.

Current configuration:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 3.0.7
- Hibernate 6.1.7.Final
- Postgres 14.7

I'm not using explicit hibernate dialect declaration. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74582515/5995606) - hibernate should configure dialect itself.

My current JPA repository code:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({
    @QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.DEFAULT_BATCH_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
    @QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, value = "false"),
    @QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.JAKARTA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, value = "-2"),
    @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.lockMode.ps", value = "NONE")
})
@Query(value = """
    SELECT p
    FROM Payment p
        JOIN FETCH p.status ps
    WHERE ps.name IN :statuses
""")
Stream<Payment> getPaymentsStream(@Param("statuses") List<String> statuses);
```

What do I expect:

```
SELECT p1_0.*, --just skipped fields
    s1_0.id,
    s1_0.name
FROM
    payment p1_0
JOIN payment_status s1_0 ON
    s1_0.id = p1_0.status_id
    s1_0.name IN(?,?)
FOR UPDATE OF p1_0 SKIP LOCKED
```

What I get

```
SELECT p1_0.*, --just skipped fields
    s1_0.id,
    s1_0.name
FROM
    payment p1_0
JOIN payment_status s1_0 ON
    s1_0.id = p1_0.status_id
    s1_0.name IN(?,?)

select id from payment_status where id =? for update skip locked
select id from payment where id =? for update skip locked
```

I've added `org.hibernate.lockMode.ps` hint according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842764/5995606) answer but nothing changed.
Also, I've already tested with `nativeQuery = true` and everything works fine. But I don't want to use this approach due to possible compatibility issues.

Are there any ways to make `FOR UPDATE OF` work in Hibernate without writing native queries?

Thank you in advance.

**UPD1**

Entity declarations

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "payment", schema = "xxx")
@ToString
public class Payment implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    /* column definitions */
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    private PaymentStatus status;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "payment_status", schema = "xxx")
@ToString
public class PaymentStatus implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide entities' declaration?

Comment: @SemyonKirekov, updated my question with declarations

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain familiar with pessimistic write locking. I only know about pessimistic locking (without the word "write"). It seems to be a very vendor specific thing.

I think it is a very special vendor thing that is more than part of the SQL syntax and semantic. I think pessimistic **write** locking is a deep cut in the cache behavior hibernate does not provide nativly.

Comment: The fact is - write locking works. But not the way I expect to.